# Passing values to class constructor (variables vs array)

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have a class named Items, on instantiation the class should receive 5+ values.
I know that passing more than (3-4) variables to the constructor indicates a poor design.

What is the best practice for passing this number of variables to constructor?

My first option:

```
class Items {

    protected $name;
    protected $description;
    protected $price;
    protected $photo;
    protected $type;

    public function __construct($name, $description, $price, $photo, $type)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->photo = $photo;
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function name()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

and the second option:

```
class Items {
    protected $attributes;

    public function __construct(array $attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
    }

    public function name()
    {
        return $this->attributes['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should Use a mixed solution. Pass array into constructor. In constructor `extract` that array and assign variables individually. Extract reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: All ok except method `name` in the `Items`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have well architecture with first solution. But if your properties are dynamic and you don't know what they are you can implement it with second solution. In that case you can use modified second option:

```
class Items {
    protected $attributes;

    public function __construct(array $attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
    }

    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }
}

$items = new Items($attributes);

foreach ($items->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
    echo $attribute->name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is the best i can get, i can call $items->getAttributes() ->name with O(1) time complexity, instead of O(n) using a loop each time. cheers :)